# DirtyForms does not work properly when used with submitHandler() method of jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-dirtyforms

I'm using both [DirtyForms](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms) and the popupar [jQuery Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate my forms. I also need to use the `submitHandler()` method because I do a couple of actions before actually sending the form.
In this scenario, DirtyForms is triggered even on a normal submit form, when it shouldn't be.

```js
$('.validate').validate({
 // submitHandler causer DirtyForms to be triggered evn on normal form submit
  submitHandler: function (form) {
    // do a couple of things here, then...
    form.submit();
  }
});

$('form[method="post"]').dirtyForms();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.dirtyforms/2.0.0/jquery.dirtyforms.min.js"></script>

<p>Fill the field and send the form, you'll see that DirtyForms is triggered even if it should not</p>
<form action="#" method="post" class="validate">
  <input type="text" name="username" required>
  <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

Please, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `submitHandler` only fires when the form is valid, you will never need DirtyForms to do anything here.

So just kill it within `submitHandler` using `.dirtyForms('setClean')`

```
$('.validate').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        // do a couple of things here, then...
        $('form:dirty').dirtyForms('setClean');  // <- kill DirtyForms
        form.submit();
    }
});

$('form[method="post"]').dirtyForms();
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/aunpmfsa/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/aunpmfsa/1/)**